# python unittest sharing object instances between tests

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am writing some unit tests in Python and it seems that my tests are somehow sharing the objects between the test functions which seem weird to be. So, I have something like:

```
import unittest 

class TestMyMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_create(self):
        c = MyClass()
        c.create_customer('Luca')
        self.assertEqual(len(c.data), 1)

    def test_connect(self):
        c = MyClass()
        c.connect_customer('Angela', 'Peter')
        self.assertEqual(len(c.data), 2)
```

If I comment any of the test out, the other one passes but the two together fail. On examination, it seems that the `c` object persists between the two test functions but why should this be? In the function new instances are created. Is this some "feature" from the `unittest` framework?

```
from collections import defaultdict
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = defaultdict()

    def create_customer(self, cust):
        if cust not in self.data:
            self.data[cust] = list()

    def connect_customer(self, a, b):
        if a not in self.data:
            self.data[a] = list()

        if b not in self.data:
            self.data[b] = list()

        self.data[a].append(b)
```

OK, this is weird. I looked at the history and before I had this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, data=defaultdict()):
        self.data = data
```

And the tests were not working when I was initializing like this. It actually works now. I must have deleted this an not kept track.

Does anyone know why this does not work? but doing `self.data = defaultdict()` is fine.

Comment: Could it be that `data` is an attribute of the `MyClass` class itself?

Comment: Or just instantiate in the setUp, which will de-couple the tests connecting to each other like that.

Comment: No, it is not a static member.... It is a instance attribute...

Comment: @idjaw Thanks for the tip but I also want to know if this is something from the framework or something more sinister is lurking...

Comment: Share your `MyClass`, please.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Added the code.

Comment: @Luca I just copy pasted your code and ran it and everything is passing for me.

Comment: @idjaw Damn...that is so weird...

Comment: @Luca You might need to dive a little deeper with your debugger to see what is happening. Sorry, from my end I'm not able to reproduce right now.

Comment: @Luca I copied and pasted your code and ran it and everything is passing for me too.

Comment: Ok, I will look into more detail and update!

Comment: @Luca, share your failed test's Traceback, please!

Comment: @StanZeez I found the problem. It was my oversight as well. 5 minutes ago, I had a different constructor which was failing. Please see the last edit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because you were using a mutable object as the default value of a method parameter. The object is created once and then shared among all calls of that method, regardless of which value `self` contains.

https://python-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/gotchas/

Comment: Yep. your most recent edit @Luca highlighted the issue. Glad someone got to quickly!. Knowing what the problem is now, there is a really good answer that explains this further as well. I'll flag it as a duplicate so you can further read. Cheers.